# How do I count total items in a column based off of both ID and date without using a for loop?

Tags: r

I have a column of dates [6-13 6-13 7-13 ...], IDs, [1 27 34 555 ...] and a column of 1's and 2's which represent an event on that day. I am trying to count, for each date given and each ID given, the total number of 1 and twos (or just the total number of days that match day and ID). In another language we might write something similar to the below psuedo-code:

```
For ID in IDs
    For Date in Dates
       *count the number of days  where ID == ID and Date == Date*
```

How can I do this without a loop?

Comment: Use  a group by operation.  i.e.`library(dplyr); df1  %>% count(date, ID, anotherCol)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   count(date, ID, anotherCol)
```

Answer (score 0):

From @akrun comment:

Use a group by operation. i.e.library(dplyr); df1 %>% count(date, ID, anotherCol)